# Flutter Interactive Viewer display zoom out version of the image

Tags: flutter, dart

so I tried to implement the Interactive widget, the scroll, zoom in & out works fine.
but while initial render I am facing a hiccup, it displays the zoomed-in image.
what I want to oom out so the entire image is visible & the user can interact.
here is my code.
a little bit of googling tells me we can achieve the same with matrix4 identity or toScene method, & that is little beyond my skill set, can someone help here?

```
InteractiveViewer(
  transformationController: mapController,
  minScale: 0.1,
  maxScale: 1.5,
  constrained: false,
  // scaleEnabled: false,
  child: Image.network(
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502920514313-52581002a659'),
)
```

here is zoomed in an image which displays on the initial render and what I want is 1st option where I can see at least some portion of the image for it to make sense to the user.
https://ibb.co/HYnZBvG (Desired result)
https://ibb.co/xg0nxnH (actual result)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you did'nt gave any fit arguments to Image Widget
just give BoxFit.fitWidth to render image with respect to Width  or BoxFit.fitHeight to render image with respect to height
and try setting constraints to true

```
InteractiveViewer(
  transformationController: mapController,
  minScale: 0.1,
  maxScale: 1.5,
  constrained: false,
  // scaleEnabled: false,
   child: Image.network(
   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo- 
    15029205143152581002a659',fit:BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
)
```

Comment: try setting constraints to true

Comment: I want the constraints to be false, as I want user to interact with scroll on the image. Its just ok initial load I want the centre of the image to display and not the top left portion

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed this issue

```
final TransformationController _transformationController =
  TransformationController();
  Animation<Matrix4>? _animationReset;
  late final AnimationController _controllerReset;

 void _onAnimateReset() {
    _transformationController.value = _animationReset!.value;
    if (!_controllerReset.isAnimating) {
      _animationReset!.removeListener(_onAnimateReset);
      _animationReset = null;
      _controllerReset.reset();
    }
  }

  void _animateResetInitialize() {
    _controllerReset.reset();
    _animationReset = Matrix4Tween(
      begin: _transformationController.value,
      end: Matrix4.identity(),
    ).animate(_controllerReset);
    _animationReset!.addListener(_onAnimateReset);
    _controllerReset.forward();
  }

// Stop a running reset to home transform animation.
  void _animateResetStop() {
    _controllerReset.stop();
    _animationReset?.removeListener(_onAnimateReset);
    _animationReset = null;
    _controllerReset.reset();
  }

  void _onInteractionStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
    // If the user tries to cause a transformation while the reset animation is
    // running, cancel the reset animation.
    if (_controllerReset.status == AnimationStatus.forward) {
      _animateResetStop();
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    _initializeViewer();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerReset.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  _initializeViewer(){
    _controllerReset = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );
  }

InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: _transformationController,
              onInteractionStart: _onInteractionStart,
              panEnabled: false,
              // Set it to false to prevent panning.
              boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(space80),
              minScale: 0.1,
              maxScale: 6.0,
              child: imageWidgetHere
            ),
```